# Why is it not putting the converted file into the desktop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So part of what I'm doing wants me to choose a .docx file convert it to a pdf and store it somewhere. I think I'm storing it on the desktop but I don't see it (I get no errors when running the code). What is wrong?

```
def thing():
    window.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                               filetypes=(("word documents", "*.docx"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    print(window.filename)
    

    in_file = window.filename
    out_file = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')

    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
    doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=17)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()


b = Button(window, text="Test", command=select_file)
b.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't you have to provide a file name for `doc.SaveAs`?

Comment: i did, it takes the path

Comment: `out_file` points to `Desktop` directory, not a file.